# Parallels keyboard shortcut mappings

Tags: macos, windows-8, parallels

I'm running Windows 8 through Parallels and I seem to have to map every <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>other key</kbd> combination for my VM separately.

Is there a way to do wildcard mapping so that, for example, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + **anything** maps to <kbd>Win</kbd> + **anything** or do I have to map every key combination explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

In windows, open up a new notepad and paste the following into it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,05,00,00,00,5b,e0 ,1d,00,1d,00,5b,e0,\
5c,e0,1d,e0,1d,e0,5c,e0,00,00,00,00
```

Save this as key.reg (or any name really, just make it .reg) and then run it to add to the registry. Then, restart your VM and it should be remapped.

Comment: Please could you explain what this registry change is doing? Editing my registry makes me nervous!

Comment: Because normally the ctrl button acts as the windows key, both keys are flipped to fix your problem.